# Show raw text with no word wrap and still scrollable

Tags: android

I need the ability to display a raw text file into a view and not have it word wrap.  The user can then scroll horizontally and vertically.

Is there a view and view settings that can do this?  I have tried loading the file and filling a TextView.  I have also tried loading the file directly into a webView.  With both, I have not been able to find the correct settings to not get it to not wrap and scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the ones you suggested dont work I would try a html page that has the raw text in a pre or code section next..

Comment: This seems to be the only real solution.